# Not able to access appended element by id

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following query:

```
$("#myModal #checks").append('<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" id="checking" value="'+[count]+'"></label></div>');
```

I have to access the checkbox in some other function to see if the checkbox is checked or not. But i am not getting how to get the checkbox element. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're giving the checkbox element id "checking" so you can use this to access it later:

```
var checked = $('#checking').val();
```